# error when I post my app-bundle on google play console

Tags: android, google-play, expo, google-play-console

I have post an app-bundle on the Google Play Console few day ago, there found a mistake about Location permission, so I filled a form to explain why we doesn't use the location on my app.

But this morning, they send me an email to says my application was refused... with this email:

```
Option 1: File an exception and roll out a submission (without making changes)

During the extended timeline for compliance, you will be allowed to roll out your latest submission without making any changes by requesting a Location exception. Here’s how:
1.  Sign in to your Play Console
2.  Select your app.
3.  Navigate to the Permissions Declaration Form.  
4.  To file an exception in the form, go to the question “Does your app meet the Location permissions policy?” and select “No, this app does not meet the Location permissions policy.”
Selecting this option will allow you to access location in the background in your latest submission, in any updates to your app, or when submitting a new app, until the dates mentioned above. For more information, please visit our Help Center.
5.  Submit your app.
Option 2: Submit a compliant update

Once you’re ready to submit a compliant version of your app:
1.  Make the necessary updates to address the issue(s) identified above.
If your app is not eligible to access location in the background or does not meet requirements for accessing location in the background, please remove the permission from your manifest and in-app functionality.
2.  Double check that your app is compliant with all other Developer Program Policies. 
3.  Sign in to your Play Console and submit the update to your app.
```

the problem is: I don't understand anything about the Google Play console, there is so much tab everything is complicated to understand.

How I'm suppose to do the `Option 1` ? The `Permissions Declaration Form` is nowhere. The question “Does your app meet the Location permissions policy?” is nowhere !

So I have update some thing in my app, change the `versionCode` to `2` in my app.json, create the the app-bundle and then :

[image]

click on blue button "create a release" upload my new app-bundle. The error still here:

[image]

And I have 2 releases ! How I can delete one ?

I have also tried to delete my app but nothing about this. Did I have to create a new app with the same name but the new app-bundle ?

Answer (score 0):

remove permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
```

and go to google play console

1. select app
2. select App content
3. select Sensitive app permissions
4. select manage
5. select No, this app does not meet the location permissions policy

Comment: There is NO Manage in sensitive app permissions. My previous APK has location permission. But now i removed in latest version and this latest version we unable to submit to google play store.

Comment: Having the same issues is @HarshBhavsar. Any solution?

Comment: No i didnt get solution yet. Even I posted another question on stack overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66288767/location-permission-declaration-needs-to-be-updated-even-after-removed-permissio

Comment: @HarshBhavsar did you find the solution i am facing the same problem.