# Google Play - File an exception and roll out a submission

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have released a version of an application that collects background information and I received a notice from google play that it is rejected. Google has outlined next steps as either submitting a compliant update by Jan 1 2021 or requesting an exception. I am a bit confused about exactly what to do though as I don't understand what they mean by 'submit' app. Do I need to make another release once I either declare an exception or submit the declaration form filled out?

Option 1: File an exception and roll out a submission (without making changes)

During the extended timeline for compliance, you will be allowed to roll out your latest submission without making any changes by requesting a Location exception. Here’s how:

1. Sign in to your Play Console
2. Select your app.
3. Navigate to the Permissions Declaration Form.
4. To file an exception in the form, go to the question “Does your app meet the Location permissions policy?” and select “No, this app does not meet the Location permissions policy.”
   Selecting this option will allow you to access location in the background in your latest submission, in any updates to your app, or when submitting a new app, until the dates mentioned above. For more information, please visit our Help Center.
5. Submit your app.

Option 2: Submit a compliant update

Once you’re ready to submit a compliant version of your app:

1. Make the necessary updates to address the issue(s) identified above.
   If your app is not eligible to access location in the background or does not meet requirements for accessing location in the background, please remove the permission from your manifest and in-app functionality.
2. Double check that your app is compliant with all other Developer Program Policies.
3. Sign in to your Play Console and submit the update to your app.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64794380/14208424)

remove permission

and go to google play console

- select app
- select App content
- select Sensitive app permissions
- select manage
- select No, this app does not meet the location permissions policy

Comment: Has anyone been able to do this in the new Google Play Console? I can't find the 'App content' button anywhere.

Comment: @Michiel check on your left side (navigation menu), under Policy, there is the App Content.