# Location permission declaration needs to be updated even after removed permission - App Content - Reject Google Play Console

Tags: android, flutter, apk, android-permissions, google-play-console

I am facing one problem regarding Android app new version publishing.

**Scenario** :

I uploaded initial flutter android app 2 month ago (Dec 2020) to google play store where we had accidentally added Location permission even with no use in code. (Just permission added in Android Manifest).

Now we come up with new version of flutter android app and trying to create new Release version 1.0.2 it shows error while Submitting new release version of app.

> Error : **Fix errors to rollout this release**

Issue is regarding used location permission in my initial app version which is live on play store

> Issue need to be fixed : **Your background location permission
> declaration needs to be updated.**

In the **App Content** it showing error in **Sensitive app permissions**

Note : In Sensitive app permission - Location Permission. It's not showing **Manage** Button instead there is a option to location permission declaration form.

> **We don't want to use location permission now . so we removed location**
> **permissions and trying to upload new release version but still this**
> **location permission (Sensitive App permission) declaration showing**
> **error again and again.**

Comment: may be this helps,https://stackoverflow.com/a/65791133/13418165

Comment: I tried that removed all newly added versions. but manage button not showing in Sensitive permissions.

Answer (score 6):

**Solution** :

1. First of all fill-out form of declaration for location permission (Any Sensitive permission used in previous rolled out APK version). This will fixed temporary error of App Content - Sensitive Permission Issue.

   In my scenario i have added no usage of background location In
   declaration and random youtube video link.
2. After permission declaration you can create/edit new release.
   Make sure before adding new release APK to console please analyse APK and make sure that that sensitive permission is not used again. (If you used that sensitive permission again than you need to add valid sensitive permission declaration in AppContent -> Sensitive Permission)
3. After Creating new release version you can roll out new release version from Release dashboard.
4. After Roll out go to  **App content -> Sensitive App Permissions** -> click on **Manage** and Select No Radio Button and Save it.
5. ITS DONE. Your new release version app will be live soon!

Comment: This worked for me. Make sure in step 2 that you create a new release for every development track, not just your production track, and include your APK that doesn't require sensitive permissions for each release. It's absolutely extraordinary how useless Google support has been for me in resolving this issue

Comment: I had issues with partial rollout. I had to change the rollout to 100%, because with Google's logic it's better to leave things as is than to fix them partially...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - I didn't need anymore this permission but the APK in prod used this permission (and also some releases of some tests) so the console let me only explain why I needed this permission and didn't display the question if I **do use this permission**.

When I tried to add new tests I was always rejected because I didn't have a good reason why I needed the background access permission.
**If you don't need this permission anymore:**
(I don't have the exact name of the sections, actions because I have a non-english language in Google Play Console)

I found a solution that worked for me: [App Update is rejected from google play due to Background Location access (But I didn't use any background location Permission)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65536318/app-update-is-rejected-from-google-play-due-to-background-location-access-but-i/65791133#65791133).

In **App content** -> **Sensitive App Permissions** -> click on **Manage** -> Click on **Display APKs...**. You will see all the APKs that use the background permission. Those APKs can be used in Tests or Production.In order to fix the problem you will need this list to be empty.
APK from Test sections:
For each test - search the source of the release (a release from a test of internal tests/closed tests...)
Under the test section, click on **Manage** (even for suspended tests), click on **New Release** and add an empty release (without APK) click to examine the release.[Add a new empty release under the test/s that uses a release with an APK that requires the background access permission. Don't add new empty tests].

APK from Production:
You will have to add a new release on Production that doesn't include the background permission.

Now you will see that no APK is displayed when clicking on **Display APks...** on **Sensitive permission..**. Now when clicking on Manage (under **Sensitive permission..**) you will have a new question - if you do use the background access. Click on "No" and now you can add new Tests.

Comment: In App content -> Sensitive App Permissions  : Manage button is not avaialable. Only Start button is visible where i need to declare usage of location permission.

Comment: If you click on start what do you see? if you have the question if you do use the background access so click on "No" else check if you have a button of which APKs use this permission and see my answer how to remove them so that you will have the question if you do use the background access

Comment: If i click start then its guiding me for my previous APK (which has permission) to declare purpose of location service. Even in my latest version apk there is no mentioned of location permission (As i analyzed APK before creating new release).

There is no "NO" or "MANAGE" button in sensitive App permissions

Comment: I am also having the same issue, please please update if you find a solution @HarshBhavsar

Comment: Yes sure. I am in talk with google developer support. I will update if found any solution.

Comment: @Mr.Rao Please try my solution it works for me. Check my answer.

Comment: @HarshBhavsar, there is no radio button option now. there is no way to say NO.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that an outdated APK/App bundle file was added to the Alpha/Beta testing phase (but never moved to production), and rather than correcting it, he added a new APK/App bundle to the live environment. The Alpha/Beta file is currently being reviewed rather than the new production file due to changes in how reviews are carried out by Google. In Google's denial, you can see the versionCode of the previous APK/App bundle.

The new APK/App bundle file should therefore be added to the same Alpha/Beta as the old one before being promoted to production. Once you have done that, go back to APP CONTENT and you will see there yes/no form. Issue is resolved.